# Why coffeescript use « return » statement everywhere?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

When writing something like that:

```
$(document).ready ->
  doSomething()

doSomething = ->
  alert('Nothing to do')
```

is compiled into

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return doSomething();
});

doSomething = function() {
  return alert('Nothing to do');
};
```

In my understand, the return statement is for values (string, array, integer...)

Why coffeescript do that ?

Comment: just to write uniform/nicely script and `return alert('Nothing to do');` == return;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CoffeeScript uses an implicit return if none is specified.

CS returns the value of the last statement in a function. This means the generated JS will have a `return` of the value of the last statement since JS requires an explicit `return`.

> the return statement is for values (string, array, integer...)

Yes, and those values may be returned by calling a function, like `doSomething()` or `alert()` in your example. That the values are the result of executing a method is immaterial.

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript, like Ruby, always returns the last statement in a function. The last statement will always evaluate to either a value (string, array, integer, etc) or `null`. In either case, it's perfectly valid to return the result.

To answer 'why' coffescript does this with all functions, instead of only ones where there is a value, it's simply because in many cases, Coffeescript can't tell when the last statement will evaluate to a value or `null`. It's much safer and simpler to always have the `return` statement there, and there aren't any negative consequences. If you don't care what the function returns, you can just ignore the returned value.

Comment: CS can *never* determine if the last statement will evaluate to a value "or" `null` without executing it under a complete environment. It puts the `return` there because the result of executing the last statement is returned--there's no thought given at *all* to what the results of executing it will be.